# Detecting HTTP close using inet

Tags: http, erlang, mochiweb, inet

In my mochiweb application, I am using a long held HTTP request. I wanted to detect when the connection with the user died, and I figured out how to do that by doing:

```
Socket = Req:get(socket),
inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
receive
     {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
             % handle clean up
     Data ->
             % do something 
end.
```

This works when: user closes his tab/browser or refreshes the page. However, when the internet connection dies suddenly (say wifi signal lost all of a sudden), or when the browser crashes abnormally, I am not able to detect a tcp close.

Am I missing something, or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [TCP keepalive protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_Keepalive) and it can be enabled with `inet:setopts/2` under the option `{keepalive, Boolean}`.

I would suggest that you don't use it. The keep-alive timeout and max-retries tends to be system wide, and it is optional after all. Using timeouts on the  protocol level is better.

The HTTP protocol has the [status code Request Timeout](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.9) which you can send to the client if it seems dead.

Check out the `after` clause in receive blocks that you can use to timeout waiting for data, or use the timer module, or use `erlang:start_timer/3`. They all have different performance characteristics and resource costs.

Comment: I considered using the after clause, but in this case, my process might be an hibernating process. Would the after clause still work for an hibernating process?

Comment: No, it would not. A hibernating process wakes up when a message is sent to it. There is no hibernation timeout, so have a delayed message delivered to you to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a default "keep alive" (but can be [enabled if supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP%5FKeepalive)) protocol over TCP: in case there is a connection fault when no data is exchanged, this translates to a "silent failure".  You would need to account for this type of failure by yourself e.g. implement some form of connection probing.

How does this affect HTTP? HTTP is a stateless protocol - this means that every request is independent of every other. The "keep alive" functionality of HTTP doesn’t change that i.e. "silent failure" can still occur.

**Only when data is exchanged** can this condition be detected (or when TCP Keep Alive is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending the application level keep alive messages over HTTP chunked-encoding. Have your client/server smart enough to understand the keep alive messages and ignore them if they arrive on time or close and re-establish the connection again.